# A hosted JSON database that i can Set and Get objects

Tags: database, json

Hey I'm making a small project and I would like to use a JSON style database service where I can set and get parts of the JS object. I would like this to be completely on the front end and not require any server technologies. It dosent need to be secure as its just a hobby project. Security is a bonus.

I'm currently using HTML5 local storage.

I'm happy to pay for this as a service.

**Update 2020:** A lot has changed on the internet since this question was asked. I would recommend:

Google Cloud Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/)

- It has an authentication mechanism built in
- It has user management

Comment: Check out https://www.firebase.com/.  It's in beta though.

Comment: Firebase.com looks good.

Comment: I'm really surprised that this is the only one out there.

Comment: update: I ended up using mongolab.com. It has CORS enabled which was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.firebase.com/ does not have free plan.

Direction to go seems to select NoSQL db like MongoDB or CouchDB, and then search/compare for db as service providers.

Quick search gives [10 Online Storage APIs](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2007/11/26/10-online-storage-apis/)
That is file oriented APIs

- Adobe Share: Recently released online document sharing service from Adobe with a REST-based API that integrates with Flash, AIR and non-Adobe applications.
- Amazon S3, Simple Storage Service: Probably the best known storage API and a key element of Amazon’s pay-as-you-go infrastructure services.
- Box.net: The “Box Enabled” platform offers a choice of SOAP, REST or XML-POST APIs. Below is Fireloader, a Firefox extension which allows you to upload, and download photos, files and videos using a familiar FTP like interface. In this version Flickr, Picasa, Box.net and Youtube are supported.
- Cellblock: This multimedia sharing service offers a REST-based API.
- MoveDigital: File delivery and management services geared towards large files.
- Nirvanix: A newer entrant into this space, focused scalable, secure storage through their Storage Delivery Service (SDS). See their feature comparison vs. S3.
- Omnidrive: A well regarded REST-based API which has been used for a variety of interesting commercial integrations including direct access from Zoho.
- Open XDrive: AOL offers this storage serviced using a JSON-RPC protocol.
- Openomy: Experimental online storage service started in 2005 (although a quick check of this service over this past week indicated leaves some question about its current operating status).

ref https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8247/seeking-online-hosted-database-web-service-with-rest-api

Comment: Currently the firebase has the free plan

Comment: All of this information is outdated. These links are all broken. We should delete the question or get some new answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

- [myjson](https://myjson.com)
- [jsonbin](https://jsonbin.io)

They all currently have a free option.

Comment: Myjson is no longer available.

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to check out www.ttmsolutions.com/restjee. Its a lightweight server-side JSON ORM that doesn't require you to develop any server-side code and works with any DB.

Answer (score -1):

amidb provides hosted json service backed by elasticsearch and cassandra.
Try it out. It is free to host files and json. you only pay when you go into production.

disclaimer: I'm involved as an engineer with http://amidb.com

Comment: Appears to be down, perhaps temporarily..?

Answer (score -1):

You could try https://jsonware.com You'll get a fixed URL with your JSON. 
It can even generate random data. No installation is needed.